# Decodable structure of Google API

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I try to decode data from Google API server, and they always get to mo error like

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [CodingKeys(stringValue: "rows", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue:
>   "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "elements", intValue:
>   nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0),
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: "distance", intValue: nil)], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.",
>   underlyingError: nil))

I don't have any variants of realization of this

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
        "Абая-Саина, просп. Абая, Алматы, Казахстан"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "г. Алматы, ул. Джандосова, 6, уг. ул. Манаса, Алматы, Казахстан"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "7,2 км",
                        "value": 7241
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "16 мин.",
                        "value": 980
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

this is my key structure

```
struct Distance:Codable {
    var destination_addresses  : [String]?
    var origin_addresses : [String]?
    var rows : [row]?
    var status : String?
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey{
        case destination_addresses = "destination_addresses"
        case origin_addresses = "origin_addresses"
        case rows = "rows"
        case status = "status"
    }
}

struct row:Codable {
    var elements : [elements]?
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case elements = "elements"
    }
}
struct elements:Codable {
    var distance : [distance]?
    var duration : [duration]?
    var status : String?
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case distance = "distance"
        case duration = "duration"
        case status = "status"
    }
}
struct distance:Codable {
    var text : String?
    var value : Int?
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case text = "text"
        case value = "value"
    }
}
struct duration:Codable {
    var text : String?
    var value : Int?
    enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
        case text = "text"
        case value = "value"
    }
}
```

My decoding

```
        let root = try decoder.decode(Distance.self, from: data)
```

Comment: If names in JSON match names in your `Codable` type you don't need to define `CodingKey` type. And if case names of enum with `String` raw value match string values you don't need to write it down.

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: [This Website](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=swift) generates the needed Swift code from your JSON. Might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let destinationAddresses, originAddresses: [String]
    let rows: [Row]
    let status: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case destinationAddresses = "destination_addresses"
        case originAddresses = "origin_addresses"
        case rows, status
    }
}

struct Row: Codable {
    let elements: [Element]
}

struct Element: Codable {
    let distance, duration: Distance // your problem is here
    let status: String
}

struct Distance: Codable {
    let text: String
    let value: Int
}
```

---

```
let root = try? decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

as

```
var distance : [distance]?
var duration : [duration]?
```

are dictionaries not arrays

Also no need to create 2 strcuts for the same content `distance` and `duration` only 1 suffices as the point is in changing the key only

In addition don't use `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {` in a struct if you won't change key names as it would be useless

Comment: I think, it would be better to drop `CodingKey` declarations everywhere, and just use [`.convertFromSnakeCase`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase).